# Is this the best way to show content?

Tags: android, post, runnable

I'm relatively new in Android's world and the UI/Thread model is still confusing.

Here is what I am trying to do:

Load data from the web
Handle them
Show them
Show an AlertDialog if there is a problem

I'm currently doing like this, but I'm not sure that using many thread like that is the best way to do it.

Inside the onCreate()

```
  final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", loadingText, true);
  final AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

  new Thread(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
    try {
     loadResorts();
    } catch (ResortsRetrievalException e) {
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
       b.setMessage(R.string.resorts_retrieval_error)
       .show();
      }
     });
    }
    pd.dismiss();
   }
  }).start();
```

And my loadResorts method finishes with

```
  final BaseAdapter a = new ResortAdapter(this, R.layout.resort_item, resorts);

  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    resortsList.setAdapter(a);
   }
  });
```

I have one Thread and two calls of runOnUiThread for that. I feel that there could be a better solution without having to deal with these threads. Am I right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) - it was created for this kind of scenarios: running a background task or (long) process, while still updating the UI in correct way (on EDT).

Comment: Thanks Peter

I thought it would not solve my problem so I didn't try actually.

Now if I try to use AsyncTask. I encounter another problem

 protected void onPreExecute() {
  super.onPreExecute();
  
  prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
 }

How do I get the context?

Thank you

Comment: You have to pass it in in constructor. When extending AsyncTask, create a constructor that takes `Context` as parameter.

Comment: Ho well... if I knew it was that easy...

Thanks

Comment: be careful when popping up an alert dialog during thread execution. if the user starts another or finishes the activity where the thread is running, the alert dialog will try to come up and your app will die!

Comment: I guess this problem is solved by the usage of AsynkTask, right?